# Can I bind a MvvmCross ViewModel to ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

Below is a model class that is deserialized from json.

```
public class JsonQuestion
{
    [JsonProperty("query")]
    public string Query { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("defaultAnswer")]
    public bool DefaultAnswer { get; set; }

    public bool Answer { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a generic list view for iOS and Android that allows you to setup switch cells, text entry cells, button cells, etc. (similar to this https://github.com/bcylin/QuickTableViewController)

Here's an example of my list row model objects.

```
public class SwitchRowModel : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged, IRowModel
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
        
    private bool _isTrue;
    public bool IsTrue
    {
        get => _isTrue; 
        set => SetProperty(ref _isTrue, value);
    }

    public SwitchRowModel(bool isTrue, string label)
    {
        _isTrue = isTrue;
        Label = label;
    }
}
```

Now let's say I have a simple view model as follows:

```
public class SimpleViewModel : MvxViewModel
{

    public IList<JsonQuestion> Questions { get; set; }

    private IList<SwitchRowModel> _items;
    public IList<SwitchRowModel> Items {
        get => _items;
        set => SetProperty(ref _items, value);
    }
}
```

The tableview/recyclerview source is bound to the Items object. And rows of the tableview/recyclerview are bound to the SwitchRowModel objects. Can I bind the SwitchRowModel objects back to the JsonQuestion objects?

Is something like this possible or is it bad design?

Comment: I read this question a few times, I still have no idea what you're trying to do. Could you please rephrase it, or explain the scenario again

Comment: We need more information of code and errors. More details would be helpful.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Can you come up with some better examples of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I will post some code examples.